# Validate Apple StoreKit2 in-app purchase receipt jwsRepresentation in backend (node ideally, but anything works)

Tags: ios, jwt, in-app-purchase, storekit

How can I validate an in-app purchase JWS Representation from StoreKit2 on my backend in Node?

Its easy enough to decode the payload, but I can't find public keys that Apple uses to sign these JWS/JWTs anywhere. Any other time I've worked with JWTs, you simply used the node `jsonwebtoken` library and passed in the signers public key or shared secret key, either configured or fetched from a JWK.

I can easily decode the JWS using `node-jose` `j.JWS.createVerify().verify(jwsString, {allowEmbeddedKey: true}).then(r => obj = r)` which gives me an object like:

```
 {
  protected: [ 'alg', 'x5c' ],
  header: {
    alg: 'ES256',
    x5c: [
      'MIIEMDueU3...',
      'MII..., 
'MIICQzCCAcmgAwIBAgIILcX8iNLFS5UwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwMwZzEbMBkGA1UEAwwSQXBwbGUgUm9vdCBDQSAtIEczMSYwJAYDVQQLDB1BcHBsZSBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0...'  
    ]
  },
  payload: <Buffer 7b 22 74 72 61 6e 73 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 49 64 22 3a 22 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 38 38 36 39 31 32 38 39 30 22 2c 22 6f 72 69 67 69 6e 61 6c 54 72 61 6e 73 ... 420 more bytes>,
  signature: <Buffer f8 85 65 79 a1 dc 74 dd 90 80 0a a4 08 85 30 e7 22 80 4c 20 66 09 0b 84 fc f4 e5 57 53 da d5 6f 13 c6 8f 56 e8 29 67 5c 95 a6 27 33 47 1e fe e9 6e 41 ... 14 more bytes>,
  key: JWKBaseKeyObject {
    keystore: JWKStore {},
    length: 256,
    kty: 'EC',
    kid: 'Prod ECC Mac App Store and iTunes Store Receipt Signing',
    use: '',
    alg: ''
  }
}
```

And its easy to JSON.parse the payload and get the data I want.  But, how can i verify that its authentic using the certificate chain in the `x5c` field

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured this out. It turns out that we needed a "hardcoded" certificate to check against.

Apple has the certificates needed on [their website](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/). You have download the root certificate (since that's the one signing the entire chain), but you can also get the intermediate one.

Once you download one you convert it to `.pem`:

```
 $ openssl x509 -inform der -in apple_root.cer -out apple_root.pem
```

then all you need to do is verify them against the ones in the JWS (the following is in `PHP`, but you should get the gist):

```
if (openssl_x509_verify($jws_root_cert, $downloaded_apple_root_cert) == 1){
    //valid
}
```

Hope this helps everyone else!

Comment: This is it!  Just needed that website.  For the life of me could not find that site.  Will code it up later to check.

Comment: @Merricat I'm a bit confused. What is $jws_root_cert ? Where can I get it?

Comment: @DaronTancharoen I'm referring to `$jws_root_cert` as the last certificate in the JWS's header `x5c` field (after decoding it). If you're having trouble, see [my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69816264/8845253)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done it in Golang in this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739376/3011380)

Comment: You are only validating the root certificate from the header. Now you need to validate the entire JWS

Comment: @max did this end up working? There seems to be almost no information about how to do this with StoreKit2.

Comment: @maxcountryman it looks like it would.  Oliver's answer below is what worked for me.  The key is figuring out that Apple host the certificates on their website at https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ which was mentioned in both answers.

Answer (score 9):

It is quite challenging to piece this together from all the information, but here's how to do this in NodeJS. Note that the latest Node supports built-in crypto, which makes it much much easier. Here's my code with the necessary comments.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const {X509Certificate} = require('crypto');

async function decode(signedInfo) {

    // MARK: - Creating certs using Node's new build-in crypto
    function generateCertificate(cert) {
        // MARK: - A simple function just like the PHP's chunk_split, used in generating pem. 
        function chunk_split(body, chunklen, end) {
            chunklen = parseInt(chunklen, 10) || 76;
            end = end || '\n';
            if (chunklen < 1) {return false;}
            return body.match(new RegExp(".{0," + chunklen + "}", "g")).join(end);
        }
        return new X509Certificate(`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${chunk_split(cert,64,'\n')}-----END CERTIFICATE-----`);
    }

    // MARK: - Removing the begin/end lines and all new lines/returns from pem file for comparison
    function getPemContent(path) {
        return fs.readFileSync(path)
            .toString()
            .replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '')
            .replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '')
            .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
    }



    // MARK: - The signed info are in three parts as specified by Apple
    const parts = signedInfo.split('.');
    if (parts.length !== 3) {
        console.log('The data structure is wrong! Check it! ');
        return null;
    }
    // MARK: - All the information needed for verification is in the header
    const header = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(parts[0], "base64").toString());

    // MARK: - The chained certificates
    const certificates = header.x5c.map(cert => generateCertificate(cert));
    const chainLength = certificates.length;

    // MARK: - Leaf certificate is the last one
    const leafCert = header.x5c[chainLength-1];
    // MARK: - Download .cer file at https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. Convert to pem file with this command line: openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleRootCA-G3.cer -out AppleRootCA-G3.pem
    const AppleRootCA = getPemContent('AppleRootCA-G3.pem');
    // MARK: - The leaf cert should be the same as the Apple root cert
    const isLeafCertValid = AppleRootCA === leafCert;
    if (!isLeafCertValid) {
        console.log('Leaf cert not valid! ');
        return null;
    }

    // MARK: If there are more than one certificates in the chain, we need to verify them one by one 
    if (chainLength > 1) {
        for (var i=0; i < chainLength - 1; i++) {
            const isCertValid = certificates[i].verify(certificates[i+1].publicKey);
            if (!isCertValid) {
                console.log(`Cert ${i} not valid! `);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    return jwt.decode(signedInfo);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for such an easy to follow answer! Especially the comments about downloading / converting the cert. So essentially we can trust the jwsRepresentation if this method returns an object rather than `null`?

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 4):

You need to validate the `header` and the `payload` with the `sign` like says in the WWDC videos:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10040/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10174/

[image]

But is more complicate than you think to do this if you don't have the knownledge about JWT because there is no documentation from Apple to do this, they only say to you "use your favorite cryptographic library to verify the data".

So after doing a lot of research, finally I found a solution using `PHP 8.1` with `Laravel`.

First you need to install this library https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt:

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

Then you need to implement the following method in order to validate the `JWT` from the transaction:

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

...

public function validateJwt($jwt)
{
    $components = explode('.', $jwt);

    if (count($components) !== 3) {
        throw new \Exception('JWS string must contain 3 dot separated component.');
    }

    $header = base64_decode($components[0]);
    $headerJson = json_decode($header,true);

    $this->validateAppleRootCA($headerJson);

    $jwsParsed = (array) $this->decodeCertificate($jwt, $headerJson, 0);

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($headerJson) - 1; $i++) {
        $this->decodeCertificate($jwt, $headerJson, $i);
    }

    // If the signature and the jws is invalid, it will thrown an exception

    // If the signature and the jws is valid, it will create the $decoded object

    // You can use the $decoded object as an array if you need:

    $transactionId = $jwsParsed['transactionId'];
}

private function validateAppleRootCA($headerJson)
{
    $lastIndex = array_key_last($headerJson['x5c']);
    $certificate = $this->getCertificate($headerJson, $lastIndex);

    //  As Oliver Zhang says in their NodeJS example, download the .cer file at https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/. Convert to pem file with this command line: openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleRootCA-G3.cer -out AppleRootCA-G3.pem
    // In Laravel, this location is at storage/keys/AppleRootCA-G3.pem
    $appleRootCA = file_get_contents(storage_path('keys/AppleRootCA-G3.pem'));

    if ($certificate != $appleRootCA) {
        throw new \Exception('jws invalid');
    }
}

private function getCertificate($headerJson, $certificateIndex)
{
    $certificate = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;
    $certificate .= chunk_split($headerJson['x5c'][$certificateIndex],64,PHP_EOL);
    $certificate .= '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;

    return $certificate;
}

private function decodeCertificate($jwt, $headerJson, $certificateIndex)
{
    $certificate = $this->getCertificate($headerJson, 0);

    $cert_object = openssl_x509_read($certificate);
    $pkey_object = openssl_pkey_get_public($cert_object);
    $pkey_array = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkey_object);
    $publicKey = $pkey_array['key'];
    $jwsParsed = null;

    try {
        $jwsDecoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($publicKey, 'ES256'));
        $jwsParsed = (array) $jwsDecoded;
    } catch (SignatureInvalidException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('signature invalid');
    }

    return $jwsParsed;
}
```

To call the function, you need to pass the `jwt` from the transaction:

```
$jwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIng1YyI6WyJNSUl...';
validateJwt($jwt);
```

Comment: Your code made my day, I can't understand how Apple has that trash documentation. Only one thing, with the v2 your way to access the transactionId is not the right way. You need to add something like this $decodedTransactionInfo = JWT::Decode($decoded->data->signedTransactionInfo, new Key($publicKey, $headerJson['alg'])); and then you will have access to the transactionId and the rest of the information

Comment: And you should change the use to 
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

Comment: How could you make sure the public key in the header is from Apple? Do you need to verify with Apple Root CA?

Comment: This simply decodes the JWT but doesn't validate it against Apple's certificate.  Oliver Zhang's solution below is the correct one, I believe.

Comment: @max I added the Apple's certificate validation like Oliver Zhangs Node JS example does

Comment: @benck I added the Apple's certificate validation

Comment: if anyone is using StoreKit Testing in Xcode - just know that there is a unique "StoreKit Testing in Xcode" root certificate that you need to use to validate against, the AppleRootCA-G3 will fail.