# What fields do I verify in a x509 (as x5c header in a JWS) to prove legitimacy of the Certificate?

Tags: php, jwt, x509, storekit

I've already posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802623/validating-jws-how-do-i-make-sure-it-comes-from-a-legit-source?noredirect=1#comment123385703_69802623), but I've realized that my issue could have more to do with x509 certificate rather than JWS in general.

Here's the thing, I'm pretty new to JWS, and Apple now transmits them as part of their server-to-server communication. I'm trying to understand how to fully guarantee the validity of the JWS, because from what I understand, the signature verification only implies that the entire JWS wasn't tampered with. **I don't know how to actually verify that this payload is indeed coming from a trusted source (aka Apple)**.

Here's what I got so far (PHP):

```
//1. explode jws and decode what's needed
$components = explode('.', $jws);
$headerJson = json_decode(base64_decode($components[0]),true);
$signature = base64Url_decode($components[2]);

//2. extract all certificates from 'x5c' header
foreach ($headerJson['x5c'] as $x5c){
    $c = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;
    $c .= chunk_split($x5c,64,PHP_EOL);
    $c .= '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;
    $certificates[] = openssl_x509_read($c);
}

//3. verify validity of certificate chain (each one is signed by the next, except root cert)
for($i = 0; $i < count($certificates); $i++){
    if ($i == count($certificates) - 1){
        if (openssl_x509_verify($certificates[$i], $certificates[$i]) != 1){
            throw new Exception("Invalid Root Certificate");
        }
    }
    else{
        if (openssl_x509_verify($certificates[$i], $certificates[$i+1]) != 1){
            throw new Exception("Invalid Certificate");
        }
    }
}

//4. get public_key from first certificate
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($certificates[0]);

//5. verify entire token, including signature (using the Firebase library)
$parsed_token = (array) \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($jws, $public_key, ['ES256']);

//helper function: a simple base64 url decoder
function base64Url_decode($data){
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
```

#### Is there a specific field to check against inside the certificates (one that couldn't be spoofed) to verify the identity/source of the JWS?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the key concepts here are the same as with HTTPS connections: you should have a hard-coded "trust anchor" or "root certificate" which you have received _independently_ of the JWS, and then the "certificate chain" provides a series of links from there to the actual signature (each certificate issuer "vouches for" the next in the chain). I'm not posting as an answer, though, because I don't know exactly what the code to verify that will look like.

Comment: @IMSoP Hey, thanks for the answer. So on this note, I just found an article from September that says `For the moment, Apple has not published the root certificate used to validate the chain. We'll update this article when they do`. I just went on `https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/` and they have 4 Root Certificates (and I can see that the 4th one matches the last one in the x5c header) . So what do I do from here?

Comment: @IMSoP So, I went ahead and downloaded it, converted it to `.pem` format, and in step#3, instead of verifying the root cert with itself, I verify it with the one downloaded. It worked. So is that it? I just keep that certificate stored on server and always compare the root CA to it?

Comment: Yes, I think that's pretty much it. The general idea is that you find a certificate in the chain which is signed by your downloaded root; then one which is signed by that; and so on, until you get to the certificate that signed the JWS itself. As I say, it's about each certificate "vouching for" the next one, so that nobody can swap out a certificate in the middle without you noticing.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok so since I get 3 certificates in the x5c header, this should be the logic: the first one signs the JWS, the second one signs the first one, the third (and last) one signs the second one. Lastly, because the last one is the root, we use the downloaded one to make sure that it is signed by itself. Awesome, thank you so much! You definitely pointed me in the right direction and helped me understand this a lot better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @IMSoP for pointing me in the right direction.
When a JWS contains a chain of certificates (`x5c` header), we're supposed to have a copy of these valid certificates (or at least the root, since it validates the rest of the chain). In my case, I could find them on [Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/).

Once you download them, it's as easy as:

```
openssl_x509_verify($jws_root_cert, $downloaded_apple_root_cert);
```

Answer (score 1):

**verify jws in Java code**

```java
import cn.hutool.core.codec.Base64;
import cn.hutool.core.io.resource.ResourceUtil;
import cn.hutool.core.util.ObjectUtil;
import com.alibaba.fastjson2.JSONPath;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.ringle.framework.json.JSONUtils;
import com.ringle.framework.response.ServiceResponseStatusEnum;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

public interface ApplePayNotificationV2DTO {

  @Setter
  @Slf4j
  class NotificationV2 {

    private static Certificate appleRootCa;
    private String signedPayload;

    public NotificationV2() throws CertificateException {
      if (ObjectUtil.isNull(appleRootCa)) {
        appleRootCa = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(
            ResourceUtil.getStream("applepay/AppleRootCA-G3.cer")
        );
      }
    }

    public ResponseBodyV2DecodedPayload getResponse() {
      if (!verify()) {
        throw ServiceResponseStatusEnum.BAD_REQUEST.buildException();
      }

      var decodedJWT = JWT.decode(signedPayload);
      var payload = new String(Base64.decode(decodedJWT.getPayload()));

      log.info("Apple Pay Notification Payload={}", payload);
      return JSONUtils.fromJsonNonNull(
          payload,
          ResponseBodyV2DecodedPayload.class
      );
    }

    /**
     * 验证JWT
     */
    private boolean verify() {
      var valid = true;
      try {
        // 拿到 header
        var decodedJWT = JWT.decode(signedPayload);
        var header = new String(Base64.decode(decodedJWT.getHeader()));
        // 获取证书链
        var caChain = JSONUtils.<List<String>>fromJsonNonNull(
            JSONPath.extract(header, "$.x5c").toString(),
            List.class
        );
        // 获取公钥并验证根证书
        var publicKey = getPublicKeyByX5c(caChain);
        // 验证 token
        var algorithm = Algorithm.ECDSA256((ECPublicKey) publicKey, null);
        algorithm.verify(decodedJWT);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        valid = false;
        log.error("Apple Pay JWS Verify Fail", e);
      }
      return valid;
    }

    /**
     * 获取公钥
     *
     * @param x5c
     *
     * @return PublicKey
     */
    private PublicKey getPublicKeyByX5c(List<String> x5c) throws CertificateException {
      var factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
      var jwtSignCa = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(
          new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(x5c.get(0)))
      );
      var jwtRootCa = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(
          new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(x5c.get(2)))
      );

      // 验证证书是否是苹果颁发的
      try {
        appleRootCa.verify(jwtRootCa.getPublicKey());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      return jwtSignCa.getPublicKey();
    }
  }

  @Data
  @Slf4j
  class ResponseBodyV2DecodedPayload {

    private String notificationType;
    private String subtype;
    private String notificationUUID;
    private Object data;
    private String version;
    private Long signedDate;

    /**
     * 获取交易详情
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Transaction getTransaction() {
      var signedTransactionInfo = JSONPath.extract(
          JSONUtils.toJson(data),
          "$.signedTransactionInfo"
      );

      if (ObjectUtil.isNull(signedTransactionInfo)) {
        log.warn("Get ApplePay Transaction Fail : transaction is null. responseBody={}", this);
        throw ServiceResponseStatusEnum.BAD_REQUEST.buildException();
      }

      var decodedJWT = JWT.decode(signedTransactionInfo.toString());
      return JSONUtils.fromJsonNonNull(decodedJWT.getPayload(), Transaction.class);
    }
  }

  @Data
  class Transaction {

    private String environment;
    private String transactionId;
    private Long revocationDate;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.